# Android.mk and Application.mk to build OpenCV 3.2

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, android-ndk

I've downloaded [OpenCV for Android](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) **Version 3.2** and imported its java module to my project. I've copied the native (c++) codes into modules directory in `openCVLibrary320/app/src/main/jni`.

How can I create Application.mk and Android.mk for compiling this sdk? (As i know that ndk-build need these two files)

Comment: This is for an older version, but should still help you: https://github.com/quanhua92/NDK_OpenCV_AndroidStudio

Comment: It is not necessary to use .mk files. please see here https://github.com/jlhonora/opencv-android-sample

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `Java` API for OpenCV, then you may have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40746665/3051961).

However, if you want to use pre-built OpenCV static libs with `C/C++` code on NDK side then only you will require `Android.mk` and `Application.mk`. In my version of these `.mk` files, I dynamically load the required pre-built libraries from a location on my drive, So while building, `.mk` files will load the required static libs.

### Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Location of SDK on my drive
OPENCVROOT := ${HOME}/opencv-sdk-android
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES := off
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES := on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE := STATIC
include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

# Load your local .cpp and .h files here.
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hello-jni.c

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lm -llog -ldl -lz
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++11
LOCAL_LDFLAGS += -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

### Application.mk

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS += -fexceptions -frtti -std=c++11 -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

APP_ABI := all
APP_PLATFORM=android-14
```

Comment: Where do you specify which c++ files need to compiled?

Comment: Updated @MinhNguyen

Answer (score 0):

Its easy follow my all point you will do it ,

1. import your Opencv ( as u did already)
2. now goto your project Structure select app than Add new Dependencies and select your opencv Module click ok
3. Crete a class call it NativeClass.java it will contain your native function and variables
4. creat a method getMessage from JNI in your nativeClass.java and build that
   [image]
5. Now Open Terminal and wirte this

   ```
   1)  cd app/src/main

   2)  javah -d jni -classpath ../../build/intermediates/classes/debug write_your_Pakage_Name.className
    My pakage name is com.example.cvlab.ndktest
    class name -->nativeClass
   ```

   [image]
6. when u write above code in terminal click enter it will create jni folder and it will have  **header file**
7. Now copy headerfile and past it in same folder but write **.cpp** instead of **.h**
8. copy function jni function from header file and past that in your cpp file
   [image]
9. build that if shows error goto gradle file and write 
   **android.usedeprecatedndk=true**
10. Now create android.mk file in your jni folder and add this code

    ```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    #opencv
    OPENCVROOT:= your opencv location
    OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
    OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
    OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
    include ${OPENCVROOT}/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := your cpp file name

    LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
    LOCAL_MODULE := MyLibs

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
    ```
11. now create Application.mk file and write this code

    ```
    APP_STL := gnustl_static
    APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti -fexceptions
    APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
    APP_PLATFORM := android-16
    ```
12. now go to your build.gradel file and afther defultConfiguation put this

    ```
        sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
    task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        commandLine "C:/Users/do/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle /ndk-build.cmd",
                'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
                'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
                'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
    }
    ```

    Note: if you installed your android stdk and ndk than you have to give that folder location in commond line like this **C:/Users/do/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle**
13. now build that it will create **jnilibs fodler** and it will contains your libs files
14. now goto your mainjava file and load this

> static {
>       System.loadLibrary("MyLibs");
>         }

1. to call your native code write NativeClass.getMessageFromJNI()
   and show that in Text view
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Although you've requested `Android.mk` for `ndk-build`, I would like to suggest `CMake` which [Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html) recommends for use with native projects.

In that case, you could check out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43886764/2949966) which provides two solutions to integrate the OpenCV 3.2.0 SDK into the Android Project/Application. The implementation provides proper and tested integration, and it leverages the `CMakeLists.txt` scripts found within the OpenCV SDK to build and link the library modules (included 3rd Party and SDK libs) properly, and it also includes the header files to code in native C/C++ classes which are part of the project.