# how to stitch bitmaps in android using opencv?

Tags: android, opencv

Can someone please walk me through on how exactly I should do to stitch images in Android using opencv? some tutorials says I should include it as module while some says I should copy .so to jniLib folder. but no matter what I do, none of them work...a working example would help a lot too!

Comment: For installing OpenCV on Android you may try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40746665/3051961

Comment: @ZdaR yes, I've already successfully installed opencv, but I can't get it to do image stitching

Comment: Do you mean making one image from two images (stitched together) or do you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_stitching)?

Comment: @RickM. arent they the same?

Comment: isnt the link you posted stitches images into one

Comment: No they aren't.

Comment: they seem to be the same to me. i want to stitch multiple images into one