# I'm trying to install OpenCV with android studio and use C++ with it. I need to install JNI so how do I do this?

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, java-native-interface

Most of them seem to be extremely difficult to follow or don't work on new distros. Or maybe I'm just stupid.

I want it to work with OpenCV and have been following a series where they install JNI here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mF9fYdXfSD8&t=44s

But apparently that doesn't work on newer versions and there's a better way of doing it but I'll be damned if I can figure it out.

So I tried this tutorial:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

but it's giving me Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found which means somethings fucked with gradle as I tried to change it...so I'm not really all that sure what to do now. Any links or solutions on Android Studio 2.2.3 with 3.3 gradle?

Not really sure what else to do other than ask people...

If I could have any help that would be great. I'd say what I specifically tried but I don't understand enough about JNI to say what I actually tried.

I just need a very basic step by step, like I've never used Android studio before, of how to do this...because all attempts at understand here is failing me entirely.

Thanks for any help you can give :)

Comment: It's possible according to this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio?noredirect=1&lq=1 I think...that you can call openCV functions with java wrappers? But some of the links are dead and maybe I'm not understanding it right. But the video tutorials use C++ functions. Do I need to use JNI here? Specifically I want to do facial recognition and feature extraction.

Comment: Yes you would have to use NDK, if You want to use C++ API of OpenCV in Android.

Comment: So the only way to do something like I want to do (use OpenCV) is to install all that stuff. Is there a Java API of OPenCV for Android I could possibly use? If not when can I ask this question again...because I can't progress unless I figure it out.

Comment: Yes OpenCV has [Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681578/how-to-run-opencv-code-without-opencv-manager)