# How to do OpenCV v3.4.0 setup with Android Studio

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, android

I want to do openCV v3.4.0(latest version) setup with my Android studio.I have downloaded latest ndk and trying to import whole OpenCV android modules like image processing, face detection, machine learning.. everything.My android studio new ndk project is ready and working fine.

Downloaded [Latest OpenCV version(3.4.0)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/)

Documentation https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/index.html

Guys please post answers who has done setup for v3.4.0 only. please don't post any answer for OpenCV older version's.

Download:- [New project source code here and try once](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1efeMpfpx27JCyleKVSY1hZQURsKaZ2nQ/view?usp=sharing).

**SDK difference between v3.40 and v3.1.0**
[image]

Comment: Wat's the problem with OpenCV version 3.4.0 installation?

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko I don't know sir,Kind of sdk they have published is not understandable and no such updated documentations.

Comment: Have you tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40746665/3051961) of mine? Try to implement the steps in a fresh project and then report the issues if any.

Comment: Why [this steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35135495/6950238) not acceptable? Seems steps is totally same for OpenCV v3.1.0 and OpenCV v3.4.0: I'm successfully installed OpenCV v3.4.0 with that tutorial.

Comment: Hi @AndriiOmelchenko it's not same. Please download v3.4.0 SDK and look at its structure.Let me know if you got success.Thanks

Comment: @ZdaR Yes i tried it. Unable to find android SDK path inside v3.4.0

Comment: I'm already successfully installed OpenCV v3.4.0 with that tutorial. Just before mine first comment (Jan 30 at 19:01)

Comment: @AndriiOmelchenko Can you please post your answer here. Because like that steps mentioned on answer unable to find any path "select {unzipped_opencv}/sdk/java ".It would be great if I can see any sample project.For now its dark for me.Thank you

Comment: Just unzip downloaded `opencv-3.4.0-android-sdk.zip` to e.g. `c:\temp\OpenCVSDK_3_4` and then, on step "4. From Android Studio import OpenCV" from Android Studio dialog select `c:\temp\OpenCVSDK_3_4`.  There is no need to send new answer: steps are totally the same (instead OpenCVLibrary310 names).

Comment: Seems you download wrong version of library (not for Android). Try [this link](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/3.4.0/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167362/discussion-between-pankaj-kant-patel-and-andrii-omelchenko).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You download wrong (not for Android) version of OpenCV library. Download right version from https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-android/3.4.0/ by press exactly `opencv-3.4.0-android-sdk.zip`:

[image: Place of OCV40 file]

and follow instructions from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35135495/6950238) of [ssim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5611377/ssimm).