# The Use of OpenCV in Android Studio

Tags: android, python, opencv

I know OpenCV can be used in many different forms of code (C++, Python, etc.). Would it be possible to use OpenCV Python in Android Studio? If it is possible how would I do it? I already imported OpenCV into my project.

Comment: You should use `OpenCV4Android`. There's an SO answer with instructions on how to do that here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio).

Comment: No it is not possible to run Python code in Android Studio for app development, You could use Java, C++ or kotlin as of now. If you are interested in java integration then you may check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40746665/3051961) with simple instructions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV in Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27406303/opencv-in-android-studio)