# How can I integrate OpenCV-Android-SDK 4.0 with Android studio 3.4?

Tags: android, opencv, tensorflow

I'm setting up an android application for object detection and I want to deploy tflite into the project. 
I want to use OpenCV library with Android Studio.
I didn't find any instructions or documentation talking about it.

I have found how can I use OpenCV 3.1.0 with a previous version of Android Studio ( 2.*) on StackOverflow.

But I did not find any good explanation for the usage and the integration of the library.

Actually, the problem is the UI is totally different between the two versions.
How can I integrate OpenCV-android-SDK 4.0 with Android Studio 3.4.1?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run OpenCV code without OpenCv Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681578/how-to-run-opencv-code-without-opencv-manager)

Comment: I have seen that but it did not solve my problem. I have updated my question

Comment: Can you briefly define what problems are you exactly facing ?

Comment: I need to know how can I integrate and using OpenCV 4.0 with Android SDK ( Android Studio version 3.4.1 )?