# Trouble using OpenCV in Android

Tags: android, opencv, kotlin

I used [A Beginner’s Guide to Setting up OpenCV Android Library on Android Studio](https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c) as a guide to setup OpenCV in an Android Studio project. I have got the project to build and install on my phone but I am not getting a video feed from the camera (that is the `JavaCameraView` is empty).

The main issues seems to be that the  [OpenCV Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.opencv.engine) has been pulled from the google play store. :,(

I have tried the solution from the [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681578/how-to-run-opencv-code-without-opencv-manager) to try to use opencv without needing to get it off the play store, but that didn't help either.

I have all the required permissions to use use the camera on my app.

My code is pretty similar to the one from the Beginner’s Guide tutorial, but let me know if you need to see any more of my code.

My onResume:

```
public override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
        OpenCVLoader.initDebug()
    }
    loaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS)
}
```

BaseLoadCallback:

```
private val loaderCallback = object : BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    override fun onManagerConnected(status: Int) {
        when (status) {
            LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS -> {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully")
                opencv_camera_view.enableView()
                opencv_camera_view.setOnTouchListener(this@MainActivity)
            }
            else -> {
                super.onManagerConnected(status)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which version of OpenCv are you using?

Comment: I am using version 4.1.1 of the Android pack from here: https://opencv.org/releases/

Comment: I also had troubles setting up OpenCv 4.1.1 Android release with instructions working on 4.1.0 version. Did you manage to make it work for 4.1.0?

Comment: Yup, I have added the steps I took to make it work as an answer below. Good Luck :)

Comment: @vSomers can you also look at my question maybe you could help [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65362431/opencv-4-5-0-empty-javacameraview-and-javacamera2view).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are the steps that worked for me.

1. Go to the OpenCV releases page and click on Android pack link of the current version section (https://opencv.org/releases.html). I used 4.1.1
2. Unzip the file named opencv--android-sdk
3. In Android Studio, go to File > New > Import Module... and the choose /sdk and wait for the sync to finish.
4. Include open-cv as a module dependency. File -> Project Structure.
5. Select the project module(not the open-cv module we added in step 3)
6. Add the opencv as a module dependency.
7. Check in the build.gradle file is it has been added as a dependency.
8. Clean and build the project.

NOTEs

- **Do not** import  /sdk/java like most tutorials suggest.
- You do not have to copy the native libraries into your project like most tutorials suggest.

Once you have OpenCV imported, use [this](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/working-with-the-opencv-camera-for-android-rotating-orienting-and-scaling-c7006c3e1916) tutorial to get the preview to fill the preview window.

And then use [this](https://github.com/alalek/opencv/blob/3998b41d6843217e639a3ba53389222ec0620351/modules/java/generator/android-21/java/org/opencv/android/JavaCamera2View.java) version of the JavaCamera2View. JavaCamera2View uses the camera2 api.

These are the steps that worked for me, happy to be corrected if I have done something wrong.

Good Luck :)

Comment: I exactly did that and `OpenCVLoader.initDebug();` showed me success. But in JavaCameraView no image is loading. Also the  `System.loadLibrary("native-lib");` is showing couldn't find "libnative-lib.so". can you help please?

Comment: You need to use the camera2 api, I have linked to a version of the JavaCamera2View class that worked for me. 

Let me know if that workers for you.

Comment: No luck. can you share your code or see mine? btw I am using 4.5.0. I'll try on 4.1.1

Comment: Happy to look at your code, but I don't think I will be able to help as I haven't worked on Android or Java in over a year now. I'm using Flutter for all my front end needs these days.

Comment: I have added the question on the stack, please check and suggest something. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65362431/opencv-4-5-0-empty-javacameraview-and-javacamera2view)

Answer (score 1):

I use this method to set opencv 4.1.0. This should work too for 4.1.1.

1. Download [opencv](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/4.1.0/) and unzip it
2. From android studio, file -> new module -> gradle project and select the sdk directory which contain `build.gradle` file
3. Add it is as dependency module for our "app" module
4. On fragment/activity that call opencv api, add

```
if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
    OpenCVLoader.initDebug()
}
```

on either onResume or onCreateView lifecycle hook(the sample use onResume but I havent encounter any problem using it on `onCreateView`)

**Update 1. How to check if opencv installed correctly**

1. After unzip the library, we have two folder, `sdk` and `samples`.
2. Go to `samples` folder and copy its .java and .xml file from `color-blob-detection`(This sample implement JavaCameraView) folder to our blank project. I think this faster than fully import the sample.
3. Dont forget to copy the manifest file too. It add camera permision. The sample dont implement runtime permission so just toggle it manually from settings -> application -> permissions for now.

note : Read the `build.gradle` file for more setup config. eg. splitting apk, ndk support etc.

Comment: Hi, that is pretty much what I have done. 
Can you think of anything that I could have missed?

Comment: Maybe try to do simple thing like grayscaling  and show it to imageview just to be sure opencv has been setup correctly

Comment: I've never user OpenCV on android before, do you have a link to a tutorial which shows how to do grayscaling using OpenCV in Android?