# Issue with updating OpenCV android library from version 4.1.0 to 4.1.1

Tags: android-studio, opencv, build.gradle, android

We are developing native android application that uses OpenCV android library version 4.1.0. We are facing issues While migrating library to latest release version 4.1.1.

OpenCV releases,

https://opencv.org/releases/

Currently app uses OpenCV android library version 4.1.0 and it's working fine. We updated to new version 4.1.1. It run successfully without any build error. But in screen while loading opencv library it throws "Package not found" error, On Clicking this redirecting to google play store which is empty screen. Is there any issue with latest opencv library release?

We followed below link to set up OpenCV Android Library in Android Studio.
https://android.jlelse.eu/a-beginners-guide-to-setting-up-opencv-android-library-on-android-studio-19794e220f3c

Help us to solve this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57480067/8193483).

Comment: I imported SDK using the option "import gradle project" from android studio. And it's working. Thanks @nfl-x