# How to include OpenCV dependency in library added manually to AndroidStudio project

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv

I added my own library using the following answer: [How to include a library module dependency in an Android Studio project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170395/how-to-include-a-library-module-dependency-in-an-android-studio-project)

AndroidStudio seems to 'accepted' it, and now I can use methods from the library in my Android project. However, this library needs OpenCV. I integrated OpenCV successfully in my project, but it doesn't 'reach' the library. Therefore, in library's build.gradle I added the following, similar as in build.gradle of the app:

```
api project(path: ':openCVLibrary347')
```

in dependencies. The problem is, when I try to sync, I get:

```
ERROR: Failed to resolve: DegreeApp:openCVLibrary347:unspecified
```

I don't know what can be the problem here, there seems to be no answer for such a formulated question.
Here I enclose also my project 'situation'.
[image]

Comment: try to file -> invalidate caches/restart

Comment: unfortunately, still the same

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479368/trouble-using-opencv-in-android/57480067#57480067)